# Is it possible to download packages from the build farm?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many of the packages are built at http://build.willowgarage.com/ before they are pushed to the repositories.

Is it possible to get the output debs of these builds?

(If not I'll probably file an enhancement request.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10602/is-it-possible-to-download-packages-from-the-build-farm?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the release architecture here:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/release/Architecture

The Hudson builds are in the release pipeline; the last stage of which before being released publicly is:

- http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/

EDIT by kwc: ros-shadow-fixed may not have a completed set of packages, so it's use is not recommended.  If you do fetch from ros-shadow-fixed, you will have to update your entire set of ros-* debs at once as the debians are version-locked for binary compatibility.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-14**:
Thanks for the link.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-07-14**:
I recommend that you read http://www.ros.org/wiki/release/Architecture if you're interested in the definition of what is contained there.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-14**:
Is it in fact always the latest from the build farm though?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-07-14**:
caveat emptor: they are held there before going public for a reason.  You may find yourself with incomplete or broken packages if you regularly use that repository.